# Detect if a page has loaded at the top, or somewhere down the page, with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Most webpages load so that you're at the top of the page by default. If you're halfway down a page, and click Refresh/Reload, most browsers will reload the page, but you'll still be wherever you were on that page.

If you have sticky navigation that relies on scroll position, this means that your navigation may not appear correctly until you scroll.

I have tried to get the value by using something like this in jQuery:

```
var h_offset = $('.h').position();
alert(h_offset.top);
```

However, this will report 0 since my `.h` div is positioned absolutely to the top of the browser, even if I'm scrolled halfway down the page.

Is there a way to get the distance between the top of the document and where the `.h` is as far as how far down the page you've scrolled?

Comment: so look at the scroll position of the page. Whatever is the scrollable element, look at the scrollTop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to check the position of the `Y` scroll axis of the page after page load.

You can use jQuery [`.offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the offset top and left of an absolute positioned element after page load.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  console.log('scrollTop', scrollTop);

  // Get the offset (left, top) of #abs element after page load
  let { left, top } = $('#abs').offset();

  console.log('#abs top', top);

  if (scrollTop === 0) {
    // We are at the top
  } else {
    // The page is scrolled down by scrollTop pixels

    // Use scrollTop and left to calc new scroll value or set it to 0
    // You can use this to scroll the page at the top after each load
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0); 
    }, 50);
  }
});
```

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  console.log('scrollTop', scrollTop);
  
  let { left, top } = $('#abs').offset();
  
  console.log('#abs top', top);

  if (scrollTop === 0) {
    // We are at the top
  } else {
    // The page is scrolled down by scrollTop pixels

    // You can use this to scroll the page at the top after each load
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0); 
    }, 50);
  }
});
```

```css
#abs {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 2000px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Top of the page</h1>
<div style="margin-bottom: 2000px"></div>
<h1>Bottom of the page</h1>

<div id="abs"></div>
```

Comment: This answer does the trick. To keep with the overly critical nature provided elsewhere, the "Run code snippet" is irrelevant since it doesn't actually show this in action, and should likely be removed in the interest of not wasting valuable time. Also the code related to `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` should not be used, since at no point did the question request that we then scroll back up to the top of the page. Thank you.

Comment: The [code snippet](http://prntscr.com/rbmrov) shows how you can detect if the page is scrolled or not on load and it directly answers your question *"Is there a way to get the distance between the top of the document and where the .h is as far as how far down the page you've scrolled?"* because it logs the position of the `#abs` element (*possible `.h` element*) on **page load**.